# Img src via blob/b64 does not work on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, webkit

I am trying to set the src of an img tag in order to display an image. The following works on android/mac/windows, but not on iOS:

```js
let b64Bmp = pageModel.image;
this.$currentPageImage.src = `data:image/bmp;base64,${b64Bmp}`;
```

`b64Bmp` is a b64 encoded bitmap image. I also tried the same using a blob:

```js
const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(resultBlob);
this.$currentPageImage.src = blobUrl;
```

None of these solutions work on iOS specifically. Also, when trying to create a new Image object like so:

```js
const image = new Image();
image.src = ...
```

The `image.onerror` throws an error without any information.

What do I have to change to make this work on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Apparently, iOS does not display BMP files with a color depth of less than 24 bits (see https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/715255). It works now, when sending a BMP with color depth of 24 bits